# How to animate objects making Curve/Arc (Animation nodes)

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I have a house which consist of 40 blocks. I wanna make an animation in Animation nodes like this:
Blocks one by one will fly from point A to point B, but in Arc/Curve way.
I tried to make it - but they fly only in straight line. (Used this tutorial: https://youtu.be/nxygLE_j82c)
I want to make them fly to point B making Curve/Arc way (

Comment: please show us your part of the node tree which is responsible for your fly from a to b or provide blend file

Comment: so i assume you want something like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7T3O.gif

Comment: yes,exactly! How did u do this ?